# How to Disable Karma Test Runner Sound Bip

Tags: karma-runner

I'm under a karma.conf file and I'd like to know if there is a way to disable this output sound bip that comes when I do a 'grunt test' and its contain test errors.

I did a search on Google and I didn't found any related, including Karma's Website.

I think this is can be just a single property too add on my **Karma.conf**, here we go what I have so far:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    'use strict';
    config.set({
        basePath: '../',
        logLevel: config.LOG_WARN,
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
            'empty'
        ],
        exclude: [
            'empty'
        ],
        singleRun: true,
        reportSlowerThan : 500,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        reporters: ['dots', 'coverage', 'junit'],
        preprocessors: {
            // source files, that you wanna generate coverage for
            // do not include tests or libraries
            // (these files will be instrumented by Istanbul)
            'src/targets/**/*.js': ['coverage']
        },
        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'reports/coverage/test-results.xml',
            suite: 'unit'
        },
        coverageReporter: {
            type: 'html',
            dir : 'reports/coverage'
        }
    });
};
```

Don't worry for my prop values, it's a dummy one.

Comment: Is it maybe caused by the reporter plugins you are using?

Comment: Surely not, this is native on Karma